# Float HTML table caption to the right of table

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables, caption

How can I float a table caption to the right of its table?  The caption should appear to the right of the table and lined up with the top of the table.

The code below places the caption in the first column of the table.

```css
table > caption {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>This is a table caption</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Value</th>
      <th scope="col">Text</th>
      <th scope="col">Numbers</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>value 1</td>
      <td>Nam a sapien.</td>
      <td>1.23</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>value 2</td>
      <td>Nunc rutrum turpis sed pede.</td>
      <td>34.56</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really make the inner-element float out of it's container, but you can do some css magic with positioning :)

Check this example:

```css
table {
  position: relative;
}
table > caption {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>This is a table caption</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Value</th>
      <th scope="col">Text</th>
      <th scope="col">Numbers</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>value 1</td>
      <td>Nam a sapien.</td>
      <td>1.23</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>value 2</td>
      <td>Nunc rutrum turpis sed pede.</td>
      <td>34.56</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> Checked in chrome/firefox/ie11

And here is the explanation of what I did there:

1. Make sure the table is a position so i can put the caption in a known position.
2. Position the caption absolutely to the table - on the top-right corner.
3. Move the caption 100% (of it's width) to the right (using `translateX(100%)`).

Answer (score 0):

OOps! I thought OP wanted the `<caption>` vertical. Oh well, I'll leave this here just in case someone wants a vertical `<caption>`. It's rotated 90% so it get's tricky with positioning it. `<caption>` is set at `white-space:nowrap` because two or more lines throws everything off. `transform-origin: right bottom` was tricky, TBH I don't fully comprehend it, all I know is to use it if `transform` is used and the results are almost there but not quite. Like Dekel had already mentioned, `position:absolute` is needed on `<caption>` and `relative` on `<table>`.

**SNIPPET**

```css
table {
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
table > caption {
  color: red;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom:-130px;
  padding:0 0 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>This is a table caption</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Value</th>
      <th scope="col">Text</th>
      <th scope="col">Numbers</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>value 1</td>
      <td>Nam a sapien.</td>
      <td>1.23</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>value 2</td>
      <td>Nunc rutrum turpis sed pede.</td>
      <td>34.56</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```